# What is the solution of this algebraic problem?

Tags: natural-numbers

Let $a, b, n, X$ and $Y \in \mathbb{N}$. Find $X$ and $Y$ such that

$(a+b)^{n} = X + Yb$.

Comment: As of now, your question is not in acceptable format. You have to show some effort on your part if you want to get more help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using the binomial theorem, we have:

\begin{align*}
(a + b)^n &= \binom{n}{n} a^n b^0 + \binom{n}{n - 1} a^{n - 1} b + \dots + \binom{n}{1} a b^{n - 1} + \binom{n}{0} a^0 b^n \\
&= a^n + \binom{n}{n - 1} a^{n - 1} b + \dots + \binom{n}{1} a b^{n - 1} + b^n
\end{align*}

Let $Y = b^{n - 1}$ and $X = a^n + \binom{n}{n - 1} a^{n - 1} b + \dots + \binom{n}{1} a b^{n - 1}$.

Then,

\begin{align*}
X + Yb &= a^n + \binom{n}{n - 1} a^{n - 1} b + \dots + \binom{n}{1} a b^{n - 1} + (b^{n - 1}) b \\
&= \binom{n}{n} a^n b^0 + \binom{n}{n - 1} a^{n - 1} b + \dots + \binom{n}{1} a b^{n - 1} + \binom{n}{0} a^0 b^n \\
&= (a + b)^n
\end{align*}

Therefore, $X + Yb = (a + b)^n$.

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards?cb=1